# Error when trying to install scipy with docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip

I've previously installed this docker image without issues, however when I try to install it now I get the following error when it tries to install scipy:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmph2civzl1
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bp21zk09/scipy
Complete output (139 lines):
setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gbf8e3wg'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
Running from SciPy source directory.
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
  libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
  NOT AVAILABLE

/tmp/pip-build-env-dc7b76m7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

/tmp/pip-build-env-dc7b76m7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
  NOT AVAILABLE

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dc7b76m7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dc7b76m7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dc7b76m7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 583, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dc7b76m7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmph2civzl1 Check the logs for full command output.
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# VOLUME path

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8050

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

Requirements file:

```
scipy
dash
dash_core_components
dash_html_components
plotly.express
pandas
dash_table
datetime
plotly
xlrd >= 1.0.0
matplotlib
dash_daq
datetime
openpyxl
dash_extensions
```

Any help appreciated!